# Newbie with SQL: Error 1064 in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I've made my first SQL code and I don't actually know where the error is.
This is what I've done so far:

```
create user lorenadam identified loria2510;
create database instituciones;
use instituciones;
create table sector (id int, nombre char(60), actividad char(60), id_institucion int,
primary key (id)
)
create table experto (id int, dni char(9), nombre char(60),
primary key (id)
```

apparently first column is incorrect, with this message "Error Code 1064: you have a problem with your SQL syntax" but I don't know what is the problem...

Then, it says I have an error on my 7th table (the one that begins with "create table experto")... but I have no idea what it is referring to. Also, I don't know how to use the "create table if not exists" order, and I do not know if it is compulsory to use it... well, if some of you can at lear clarify some of these beginner questions for me,I'd be more than thankful. Thanks!

Comment: You miss a `;` after the end of `create table sector ... )`

Comment: create table sector (id int, nombre char(60), actividad char(60), id_institucion int,
primary key (id)
) **;**

Comment: Hi Lorena!....first, if you are not familiar with the engine, you should start with baby steps(you know, you don't eat an elephant on one bite...you need to eat it one bite at a time)....you need to start first creating your user, so just write this command: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON YourDatabaseName.* TO 'lorenadam'@'%' identified by 'loria2510' WITH GRANT OPTION;`...when you have your user ready, we can continue with the tables ;)

Comment: missing `)` at the end (create table experto).

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax is incorrect:
For the user see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-user.html

SQL statements end with a semicolon, and strings are quoted.
Convention also states you use capitals for SQL keywords:

The below works in a MySQL instance I have:

```sql
CREATE USER 'lorenadam'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'loria2510';
CREATE DATABASE instituciones;
USE instituciones;
CREATE TABLE sector (id int, nombre char(60), actividad char(60), id_institucion int, primary key (id));
CREATE TABLE experto (id int, dni char(9), nombre char(60), primary key (id));
```

Comment: This will only create a user on the LOCAL machine, you may want to use a remote machine. Remember you still need to grant permissions using grant.